# Multiple checkbox scripts intervene with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

a nice member here helped me set up a multiple checkbox example that stores the data to be shown in a div. However, when I try to do multiple of these, they interlap with each other and show the same data in the divs even when I changed variables.

I set up a simple example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/vrpMc/4/

Thank you for your time everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using the same selector in both event handlers: `input[type="checkbox"]:checked`

This will select all checked checkbox inputs in the page.

You should instead use `input[name="car[]"]:checked` and `input[name="phone[]"]:checked`
to select only the inputs with the given name, each time.

Answer (score 1):

In both your functions, you're selecting all of the selected checkboxes. My fix (and someone else might have a better one) would be to add unique ids to the ul's surrounding the li's.

html:

```
<ul id='electronics'>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="phone[]" value="Nokia" />Nokia</li>
```

That way you can modify your $('#submit').click handler to something like this:

```
$('#submit').click(
    function()
    {
        var htmls = "";
        $('ul#electronics>li>input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(
            function()
            {
                htmls += $(this).val() + " ";
            }
        );

        $('.here').html(htmls);
    }
);
```

Check out http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/, http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ for more info.

Basically, without this or a similar change, there's nothing distinguishing your list of car brands from your list of electronics brands, and your click handlers both consider all of the checked checkboxes.